# point scalar multiplication python 2.7 information leak

Tags: python, cryptography, multiplication, ellipse, scalar

I am trying to implement a point scalar double and add multiplication function which does not leak and information any possibly performs in constant time. However, the fact that it does not leak information is the most important.

**I would like to ask someone to help me our and perhaps fix the code below so that it does not leak information.** 
I have noticed that for different scalar sizes function takes different times to compute which is insecure.

Any help? please

```
def point_scalar_multiplication_double_and_add(a, b, p, x, y, scalar):
"""
Implement Point multiplication with a scalar:
    r * (x, y) = (x, y) + ... + (x, y)    (r times)

Reminder of Double and Multiply algorithm: r * P
    Q = Inf
    for i = 0 to num_bits(P)-1
        if bit i of P == 1 then
            Q = Q + P
        P = 2 * P
    return Q
"""
Q = (None, None)
P = (x, y)
binary = bin(scalar)

for i in range(scalar.num_bits()):

    if binary[scalar.num_bits()-i+1] == '1':
        Q = point_add(a, b, p, Q[0], Q[1], P[0], P[1])
        #print Q
        pass
    P = point_double(a, b, p, P[0],P[1])
    pass
return Q
```

Comment: Your question is awkward, because it's not clear what is a "constraint" that you are working under, and what is a possible optimization of your code. For example, you are implementing multiplication as "double and add", but most python code would simply multiply the elements of the point. Is that a constraint, or just something you don't know how to do?

Comment: Something I don't know. I just need to fix the function so that it works in a constant time. I know that we can measure the time it takes to execute using time.clock() for different scalars and it shows that data is leaked.

Comment: What are a, b, and p?

Comment: a,b are parameters of the the curve and p is the modulo p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I hard-coded the bit count to avoid leaking based on the value of the scalar, and tried to balance instructions regardless of whether or not an action is taken.

I can't find a 'num_bits' documented, so I assume your scalar is an object of some kind. Please adjust the NUM_BITS constant to the MAXIMUM SIZE of a scalar value (at least, the max you intend to use).

A few places were I did find mention of numbits online, it referred to the number of *active* bits, which would tend to leak data if you used it (e.g., scalar(1).num_bits() != scalar(1000).num_bits()).

**edited:**

```
def point_scalar_multiplication_double_and_add(a, b, p, x, y, scalar):
    """
    Implement Point multiplication with a scalar:
        r * (x, y) = (x, y) + ... + (x, y)    (r times)

    Reminder of Double and Multiply algorithm: r * P
        Q = Inf
        for i = 0 to num_bits(P)-1
            if bit i of P == 1 then
                Q = Q + P
            P = 2 * P
        return Q
    """
    Q = (None, None)
    Q2 = Q
    P = (x, y)
    binary = bin(scalar)
    binary = binary[2:]   # get rid of 0b

    NUM_BITS = 64
    # pre-pad binary with 0s - 1010 becomes 0000000...00001010
    binary = '0' * (NUM_BITS - len(binary)) + binary

    # reverse binary and iterate over bits
    for b in binary[::-1]:
        Q2 = point_add(a, b, p, Q[0], Q[1], P[0], P[1])
        if b == '1':
            Q = Q2
        else:
            Q2 = Q  # Useless, but balances instruction count

        P = point_double(a, b, p, P[0],P[1])

    return Q
```